# Movie set in medieval times with a dragon creature

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a movie I watched years ago as a kid (in the 90s), but I can't seem to find any info on it anywhere.

**Plot Details:**

There was a kid who lived in a castle (possibly a prince), and had a little statue of a dragon that was given to him by someone of importance to him (father?).

Bad guys show up, take over and kick the kid out - the kid cries on the dragon statue, and it comes alive and starts kicking some bad guy butt.

I can't remember what happens in the end - I know the dragon dies for some reason or another but I'm not sure how.

**Non-Plot details:**

- I watched it mid-to-late 90s, has to be at least 1994-1999 (or older, possibly 80s)
- Live Action
- Animatronic dragon (rather than CGI)

**Other Info:**

- I don't think the dragon could talk

It's not *DragonHeart* with Sean Connery by the way - wrong story (from what I've read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonheart)).

Comment: Sent this question to a movie buff and he said it sounds more like a TV show but he can't recall what it would be.

Comment: @BuildStarted - Wow thanks, I can definitely remember my parents renting it on VHS (definitely a movie) - Then it disappeared from the shelves when the shop went all DVDs - I assume it never made the re-release-to-DVD cut.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[*The Legend of Galgameth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113141/) from 1996. Some sources call it "The Adventures of Galgameth".

[image: The Legend of Galgameth cover]

According to the [Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galgameth): as he lays dying, a king gives a statue of a dragon to his son. His tears bring the statue to life and the dragon becomes the prince's friend and guardian. Together, they fight the man who usurped the throne.

If Hulu is available where you are, you can watch the whole movie [here](https://www.imdb.com/video/hulu/vi3081438233/).

Comment: Wow. yes that's it!